# Taking a stab at a Javascript Timer and failing

Tags: javascript

```
let hours =0;
let minutes = 0;
let seconds = 0;
let displayHrs = document.getElementById("hours");
let displayMins = document.getElementById("minutes");
let displaySecs = document.getElementById("seconds");



var interval;
const startBtn =  document.getElementById("start");
const stopBtn =  document.getElementById("stop");
const resetBtn =  document.getElementById("reset");


const  startTimer  = () => {

    seconds++;
    if(seconds < 9){
        displaySecs.innerHTML = "0" + seconds;
    }
    if(seconds > 9){
        displaySecs.innerHTML = seconds;
    }
   if(seconds > 60){
        minutes++;
        seconds = seconds -(minutes *60);
    }
    if (minutes < 9){
        displayMins.innerHTML = "0" + minutes;
    }
     if (minutes > 9){
        displayMins.innerHTML = minutes;
    }
     if (minutes> 60){
        hours++;
        minutes = minutes -(minutes *60);
    }
};
startBtn.onclick = () => {
   interval = setInterval( startTimer);
}
```

The simple application crashes when I click the startBtn by indicating that displaySecs is null. I watched several tutorial and tried to create my own custom timer. Are there too many if statements? Is there a simpler cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Please include your HTML as well

Comment: where is the delay argument ?  (in `setInterval( startTimer)` ), by the way `setInterval` can't be a timmer method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Note that because you don't pass an interval to `setInterval`, it will repeat on every cycle of the JavaScript event loop; basically the default for the delay argument is 0. This will have massive repercussions on the performance of the application. See [MDN's documentation of `setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way:

```js
let hours   = 0
  , minutes = 0
  , seconds = 0
  , interval
  ;
const startBtn  = document.getElementById('start')
  ,   stopBtn   = document.getElementById('stop')
  ,   resetBtn  = document.getElementById('reset')
  , displayHrs  = document.getElementById('hours')
  , displayMins = document.getElementById('minutes')
  , displaySecs = document.getElementById('seconds')
  ;
const  startTimer = () =>
  {
  seconds++
  if (seconds > 60)
    {
    minutes++;
    seconds = 0
    }   
  if (minutes > 60)
    {
    hours++;
    minutes = 0
    }
  displaySecs.textContent = ((seconds < 10)?'0':'') + seconds 
  displayMins.textContent = ((minutes < 10)?'0':'') + minutes 
  displayHrs.textContent  = ((hours < 10)?'0':'') + hours 
  }
startBtn.onclick = () =>
  {
  startBtn.disabled = true
  stopBtn.disabled  = false
  interval = setInterval( startTimer, 1000)
  }
stopBtn.onclick = () =>
  {
  startBtn.disabled = false
  stopBtn.disabled  = true
  clearInterval(interval)
  }
resetBtn.onclick = () =>
  {
  startBtn.disabled = false
  stopBtn.disabled  = true
  clearInterval(interval)
  hours = minutes = seconds = 0
  displaySecs.textContent = displayMins.textContent = displayHrs.textContent = '00'
  }
```

```html
<p>
  <span id="hours">00</span>h
  <span id="minutes">00</span>m
  <span id="seconds">00</span>s
</p>

<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop" disabled>stop</button>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
```

following the PO's comments for a request for additional explanation on:

```js
displaySecs.textContent = ((seconds < 10)?'0':'') + seconds
```

this is like

```js
displaySecs.textContent = (seconds < 10)?'0':''; // set value to character zero if the value
                                                // of second is less than 10
                                               
                                              // otherwise set an empty string

displaySecs.textContent += seconds;  // add the value of seconds
```

`(seconds < 10)?'0':''` is [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
it is like this function :

```js
function F(second) {
  if (seconds < 10) return '0'  // return string with a character of zéro
  else              return ''   // return an empty string 
}
```

Nb: your code use an oposite test `if(seconds > 9)` == if the value is **greather** than `9`.
I believe I read somewhere that testing if an integer is less than 10 requires less cycle for the processor than testing if it is supper to 9 - this needs to be verified (*but it's not very important, it's just a matter of habit*).
.

if my code was without parentheses before the `+ seconds` as:

```js
displaySecs.textContent =  (seconds < 10)?'0':''  + seconds
```

it would be interpreted as follows:

```js
displaySecs.textContent =  (seconds < 10) ? '0' : (''+ seconds)
```

and would just output the character zero for all values less than 10 (zero through nine) - which would be an error

so I have to precise the order of imperetation with correct parentheses:

```js
displaySecs.textContent = ( (seconds < 10) ? '0' : '' ) + seconds
```

hope this explanation will help you?

Comment: Very Neat @MisterJojo .I  didn't know about `.textContent `

Comment: Could you explain this part `(seconds < 10)?'0':'')`

Comment: @RoamingStatus this a ternary operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: I get that its the Ternary operator , so if seconds are Greater than ten is true and the `'0':' '` are false?

Comment: @RoamingStatus  I added explanations in my answer

Answer (score 3):

No such thing as too many if statements, as far as your program is concerned.

displaySecs is null means that `document.getElementById()` could not find the element with the matching id, so I suggest you go back and make sure that you actually have one with the id of seconds

Also check your other ones as they may possibly have the same problems.

(also I'm pretty sure your setInterval doesn't actually do 1 second intervals, you need to specify 1000 milliseconds in the parameters)

Comment: dumb mistake I had CLASS instead of ID

Comment: now my seconds add up and the minutes don't increase after 60

Comment: used 250 milliseconds

Comment: Unfortunately now after 60 seconds the minutes are also incrementing at the same rate the seconds are , i might create a different function to increment minutes, seconds and hours on their own